# How to determine the strides and padding type at each layer when implementing a cnn from its high-level architecture?

Tags: keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to build a cnn based on the architecture proposed by [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.01249.pdf). The model diagram only specifies the filter and kernel size but not stride and padding. This is my first time building a cnn from scratch so I'm not sure do I pick these values by choice or are there any rules for it?

I found some versions of this same cnn on github and they used the same value of stride and padding type at each layer, but these values are not anywhere in the paper. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can think about stride in following way:

Minimal stride (1) leads to maximum number of convolutions of source image with filters, and in case of bigger filters lots of visual information is dubbed, since same pixels are convoluted several times with different filters.
Bigger stride downscales source image stronger (and if stride is bigger than filter kernel you will get downscale with loss of visual information).

And padding only determines how to treat edges of the source image. If edges may contain some features it's reasonable to add zero-pad (smaller than filter kernel).

So you shall adjust both parameters (but mostly stride) to determine optimal number of conv net's learning parameters at each layer. I think bigger stride (lower number of learning params and downscaling) at top layers combined with smaller stride at final layers in general is a good idea to try.